# How to convert JSON to a formatted nested array?

Tags: python, json

Let's say I have JSON data consisting of latitudes, longitudes, and locations. I want to use those values and return them as an JSON string containing only latitudes and longitudes.

How do I do this in python? 
(Note: latitudes and longitudes have to be converted to float values)

Input example:

```
object =
  [{"latitude": "48.8566",
    "longitude": "2.3522",
    "location": "Paris"
   },
   {"latitude": "51.5074",
    "longitude": "-0.1278",
    "location": "London"
   }]
```

Expected Output:

```
"[[48.8566, 2.3522], [51.5074, -0.1278]]"
```

Comment: You'll need to share some code you've attempted to write. This is a request for someone to write code not solve a problem you're having. The best way to learn is to have a go! If it breaks ask a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the object to a list with latitude and longitude:

```
result = [[_.get('latitude'), _.get('longitude')] for _ in object]
```

Then use json module to dumps the list:

```
str_result = json.dumps(result)
```

Remember to import json module

Answer (score 0):

```
from json import dumps


obj = [
    {"latitude": "48.8566", "longitude": "2.3522", "location": "Paris" }, 
    {"latitude": "51.5074", "longitude": "-0.1278", "location": "London" }
]


def return_type(val):
    try:
        return type(float(val))
    except:
        return type(val)

resp = [
    [
        v
        for k, v in item.items() if return_type(v) is float
    ]
    for item in obj
]
print(dumps(resp))
```